# Shifted point cloud while plotting points collected using tfmini plus lidar and servos

Tags: arduino, project, lidar, servo

I'm doing a project of creating a 3D mapping of a room using 2 servos and a tfmini plus lidar. I'm using mg996r servo. But the point cloud I obtained is shifted such that the clockwise collected points and anticlockwise collected points are shifted by an angle.

obtained point cloud of a room

[image]

I was collecting the points using arduino uno. The two servos are mounted such that one rotates horizontally and the other rotates vertically upto 180 degrees. The points obtained was printed on to serial monitor and the values are saved into a txt file using coolterm. The points are then plotted using cloud compare software. But as seen in the image the points from clockwise scanning and anticlockwise scanning is shifted